# Where is emrfs-site.xml?

Tags: emr, amazon-emr

Where is emrfs-site.xml on the EMR master node?

Consistent view is disabled within the EMR UI but I am unable to find the configuration file to verify.

```
sudo find / -name emrfs-site.xml
```

yields

```
/var/aws/emr/bigtop-deploy/puppet/modules/emrfs/templates/emrfs-site.xml
/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf/emrfs-site.xml
```

Neither of which seem to be relevant.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is the relevant one:

```
/usr/share/aws/emr/emrfs/conf/emrfs-site.xml
```

It seems to be a strange place, but the path to the config file is hardcoded in java code. You can verify this by logging the debug output of the root logger to the console:

```
export HADOOP_ROOT_LOGGER="DEBUG,console
```

If consistent view is enabled, the following should be in that file:

```
<property>
  <name>fs.s3.consistent</name>
  <value>true</value>
</property>
```